# Oracle bulk collect into

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

What are the main applications of a bulk collect into?
Can this be used in the below?

```
select *
from table
where condition
bulk collect into variable
```

Comment: Your query has invalid syntax. You want `SELECT value1, value2, value3 BULK COLLECT INTO collection1, collection2, collection3 FROM table_name WHERE condition`.

Comment: So, bulk collect into would just work for collecting more than one variable into more than one variable?

Comment: You would use it whenever you want to populate a collection (or multiple collections) from a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the main applications of a bulk collect into?

That is too open-ended and opinionated to be able to give an answer as to the "main" applications.

> Can this be used in the below?
>
> ```
> select *
> from table
> where condition
> bulk collect into variable
> ```

No, your syntax is invalid.

You want to name the column(s) you are collecting and have one collection variable for each column:

```sql
SELECT value1
BULK COLLECT INTO collection1
FROM table_name
WHERE condition
```

> So, bulk collect into would just work for collecting more than one variable into more than one variable?

No, it is for collecting multiple rows into collection variable(s) in PL/SQL.

The [Oracle `SELECT INTO` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/SELECT-INTO-statement.html#GUID-6E14E04D-4344-45F3-BE80-979DD26C7A90) gives you the full syntax and examples; I suggest that you read it as it will give you more details.

Answer (score 1):

It is intended to fill a collection (array, "table of") with data from the query. The main difference between just select...into and select..bulk collect into is that select..into will fire up an exception when your query return more than 1 row whereas latter (bulk collect) will fill a collection you've specified after "into"

In other words, "bulk collect into" is to fill a collection and "select...into" is to fill variable(s) with values your select statement returns